# Limitations on Cloud Firestore transactions

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have read the docs regarding [transactional update operations on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/update-data). According to [Quotas and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) there are only two limits with regards to transactions:

> - Maximum size for a transaction: 10 MiB
> - Time limit for a transaction: 270 seconds, with a 60-second idle expiration time

There is no explicitly transaction-related limit mentioned, how many documents or collections can be read and/or modified during the transaction, or if there are any additional constraints on the collections in which the transactional updates happen.

1. Does it mean, a client could do a transactional update on up to 500 documents, each in different collections, as long as the update stays inside these and the other general limits?
2. If a client reads multiple documents inside a transaction, but only updates one of them - does Firestore still (silently) write into the unmodified documents (for serialization or so)... so I have to consider the write-limit of 1 write per document per second even for documents that have not been explicitly modified by the client.

P.S.: The reason I ask is that Datastore has a limit of 25 entity-groups in transactions, and also sees hotspots in entities ("documents") that are read-only inside many write transactions. For example, see [this answer by Dan McGrath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43530600/1549523). I just wonder which of Datastore's characteristics carry over to Firestore and has to be considered when designing a Firestore database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the line "Maximum number of documents that can be passed to a Commit operation" which defines a limit of 500 documents. This is your transaction limit as we need to apply everything in a transaction using a single commit.

I don't believe silent writes are required anymore to determine if a document has changed in a transaction.

There is no related limit that is equivalent to the 25 entity-group limit.

Comment: In case that we will want to do more than 500 updates, we should use multiple batchs? or how we can achieve this? I have a case where I need to update a `reference` dinamically for an `User  Feed`. Where I add to a collection the Id's + some info of each `Post` made by the user I follow, and ofc I need to delete this refs if I unfollow the user. 

Right now everything works fine, but if in a future my app grows and an user have more than 500 post, my `cloud function` will crash when trying to update this data.

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia Honestly, if you store even just a reference to every post of every user that user X followed in a collection inside user X you have bigger scalability problems than transaction limits.