# Is there an Entity Group Max Size?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an Entity that represents a Payment Method. I want to have an entity group for all the payment attempts performed with that payment method.

The 1 write-per-second limitation is fine and actually good for my use case, as there is no good reason to charge a specific credit card more frequently than that, but I could not find any specifications on the max size of an entity group.

My concern is would a very active corporate account hit any limitations in terms of number of records within an entity group (when they perform their 1 millionth transaction with us)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't a limit for the entity group size, all datastore-related limits are documented at [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

But be aware that the entity group size matters when it comes to data contention, see [Keep entity groups small](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention#keep-entity-groups-small). Please note that contention is not only happening when writing entities, but also when reading them inside transaction (see [Contention problems in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927068/contention-problems-in-google-app-engine/45496048#45496048)) or, occasionally, maybe even outside transactions (see [TransactionFailedError on GAE when no transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367551/transactionfailederror-on-gae-when-no-transaction)).

IMHO your usage case is not worth the risk of dealing with these issues (fairly difficult to debug and address), I wouldn't use a single entity group in this case.

Comment: I was hoping to make use of entity-groups here to prevent multiple requests/threads from charging a user at the same time. Currently I have separate entity I call the 'payment lock' which shares the same Key id as the account it is locking. Before attempting payment, I try to mark the account as 'locked' in a transaction, I then perform the payment and then unlock in a transaction. I have noticed contention errors from time to time. What would be the best way to do this then?

Comment: You shouldn't normally need an explicit lock, the very presence of the transaction environment should take care of that. Unless the duration of the transaction is unacceptable. By transaction here I mean a datastore transaction, not a charge transaction. Try mapping them 1:1.

Comment: If you limit your entity group ancestor to the payer then you can scale the system and still achieve the transaction capability of transaction groups unless you can come up with a reason why a single card will be paying multuple concurrent payments ;-)